# Consistent Empty Data using MediaRecorderAPI, intermittently

Tags: html, html5-video, webrtc, mediarecorder, getusermedia

I have a simple setup for Desktop Capturing using html5 libraries. 
This includes a simple webpage and a chrome-extension. I am using

1. Extension to get the sourceId
2. Using the sourceId I call navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia to get the MediaStream
3. This MediaStream is then fed into an instance of MediaRecorder for recording.

This setup works most of the times, but a few times I see that requestData() on MediaRecorder instance returns blob with empty data consistently. I am clueless as to what can cause a running setup to start misbehaving sometimes.

Some weird behaviour that I noticed in the bad state:

1. When I try to close/refresh the window it doesn't respond.
2. The MediaStreamTrack object in Step 2) above is 'live' but as soon as I go to Step 3) it becomes 'muted'.
3. There's no pattern to it, sometimes it even happens when I request for the MediaStreams the very first time(which rules out the possibility that there could be some dangling resources eating up the contexts)

Is there anything that I am doing wrong and am unaware of? Any help/pointers would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: can you post your code here? Or try referring the following
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable